# Node same buffer on write stream

Tags: node.js, stream, buffer, filestream

I have the following code

```
    const buffer = new Buffer(buffer_size);
    const wstream = fs.createWriteStream('testStream.ogg');
    do{ 
        read = obj1.partialDecrypt(buffer);
        if(read>=0){
            if(read<buffer_size){
                wstream.write(buffer.slice(0,buffer_size));
            }
            else{
                wstream.write(buffer);
            }
        }
        total+=read;

    }while(read>0);
    wstream.end();
```

In which partialDecrypt fill the buffer with binary data and return the size filled.
If I fill the buffer more than one time the data written to the stream does not match the expected. Should I do something to reuse the same buffer on the stream?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out reusing buffer is not a good idea. Like on [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nodejs/dMIWsNK58Ts), creating a new buffer each pass was the way to go.